# How to record errors & write it to a log file when using "load data infile"?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm facing a problem in using "load data local infile" for importing data from CSV file.
When there's a constraint problem in some of the records, the entire records failed to insert.

I have used :

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...";
$exec = mysql_unbuffered_query($sql);
if ($exec === false) {
    echo "mysql_error : ".mysql_error()."<br/>";
}
else {
    echo "Success execute";
}
```

But it keeps terminating the query.

What I expect to do is continue inserting records **except** for some records that have a constraint problem, and capture/record the error + the data to a log file using PHP.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
<?php

$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...";
$exec = mysql_unbuffered_query($sql);
if ($exec === false) {
    $error_message = "mysql_error : ".mysql_error()."\n";
    error_log($error_message, 3, "your_log_file.txt");
}
else {
    echo "Success execute";
}

?>
```

---

***P.S.** And also try accepting answers as @ManseUK mentioned; it's an indication that you respect the community (and the community will be more than happy to help you more, next time...)*

Comment: @ManseUK, Thanks for remaining me :), I have check the link, it means I have to check the mark in a right answer?

Comment: @Yagi This is how the community works : you like an answer/question? you UPvote it. you don't? you downvote it. If it's an answer on your OWN question, and you find it acceptable, then click the tick next to it, so that the community knows that it really **is** the correct answer. Simple as that... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried that but it keeps terminating the inserting process. So, when the constraint is in the first record, the next record is not inserted to the table. On the other hand, if I use "insert into" syntax, the next record is inserted to the table and all the errors of some records can be captured to an array & write them to a log file.

Comment: Anyway, Dr.Kameleon, Thanks for your explanation about "accepting answer", I understand now :)